# lightweight php&mysql distribution

Tags: php, mysql

I need a **XAMPP** like but a lighter version. All I need is to run **PHP** and **MySQL** scripts.Please help me on how and what application should need to download.

Comment: The lightest possible setup I can think of is downloading MySQL and PHP, then installing them manually. If you need a web server, download Apache and install it manually. You can try that if it's not too much of a hassle.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use WAMP. I have used both XAMPP and WAMP, and to me WAMP is much more simpler than XAMPP. I am afraid it also has Apache Server with PHP and MySQL. [Here](http://www.wampserver.com/en/download.php) is the link.

Comment: WAMP for the win

Comment: He only wants PHP + MySQL, without any webserver. WAMP ftl in this case..

Comment: @f00: For the lin I think there is LAMP :-)

Answer (score 2):

Create your own, its not that hard to do.. all you need is a tutorial to get you started ;)

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/tutorials/wa-phpmysql/index.html

http://www.ricocheting.com/how-to-install-on-windows/mysql

http://php.about.com/od/phpbasics/ss/php_mysql_5.htm

And its not really that hard to be honest, just install apach php and mysql like so:

```
c:/server/        ##Apache
c:/server/php/    ##Php
c:/server/mysql/  ##Mysql
```

And then just follow the guide to setting up the directories and modules / extentions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Denwer. [Link](http://denwer.ru). He is very light.

Comment: Does that have an option to exclude PostgreSQL from the setup?

Comment: Yes, Denwer includes MySQL(i)/PostgreSQL/MSSQL, PEAR, PECL by default. All additional extensions install very easy.

Comment: He asked if it's possible to EXCLUDE PostgreSQL..

Comment: Thank you for this. Even if I don't understant the site but I see the application it is very light. 6mb.

Comment: It is impossible to exclude Postgre from setup. But why you want to excude? All unused extensions you can put off after installing.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is EasyPHP (http://www.easyphp.org/download.php), but this still comes with an Apache 2.2. Other than that I guess you have to install PHP5 (http://www.php.net/downloads.php#v5) + MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) yourself. Download packages for Windows are available under the above links.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: Is WAMP a bad option?

Comment: It still comes with an Apache. To my understanding he just wants PHP + MySQL without any webserver.